# Change div value based on textbox value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this fiddle that the div value changes based on your dropdown list selection. http://jsfiddle.net/qSkZW/20/

I want to take it one step further and this is to create a textbox field that if you add for example the number `2` it will change the div value to 240 (in real the 120 you find in the script it will be a php var). If it writes `3` then to 360.

Additionally there must be two limitations.

1. Prevent them from using non-numeric characters.
2. The maximum number is pre-configured (from a php variable). Like if the max value is set to 10, if the user writes 30 it will return to 10.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What should happen if they type in something that isn't a number?  Or do you want to prevent them from typing non-numeric characters?

Comment: @amosrivera I tried (and obviously did) the dropdown method because it is the one I knew how to do it as a beginner.

Comment: @Dennis, yes I would like to prevent them by entering non-numeric chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so first, create a textfield (example id="textfield"), then modify your listener's action to

```
$("#quantity").change(function () {
    var price = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)*120
    $("#textfield").attr('value="'+price+'"');
    # sets the default value of #textfield to the selection from #quantity
    })
.change()

$("#textfield").blur(function () {
# when the element looses focus (they click/tab somewhere else)
        var valid = /^\d{2}$/;
        # this means any 2 numbers. change {2} to {3} or however many digits.
        # you can also also use d[0-10] to identify a range of numbers.

    if ( $(this).text() != valid ) {
        $("#message").text("Only numbers please!");
        $("#message").fadeIn();
        # add <span id="message" style="display:none;"></span> next to #textfield
        # enclose #textfield & #message in the same element (like <li> or <div>)
    }
    else {
        $("#message").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Could you please provide more info about #2 (I don't have a clear understanding of what is supposed to happen)

Quick question: why are you trying to put a price in an editable element?

Comment: Yes, I will pass a variable into the script that the user will not be allowed to type a bigger number than this.

Comment: i still don't understand what you mean by converting 30 to 10…Are you actually trying to do the reverse (a user types 10 into the textfield, and the dropdown changes to 10, but if the user types 30, the dropdown will only go to 10?)

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = 30;
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    v = isNaN(v)?'':v;
    v = v > max ? max : v;
    $(this).val(v);
    $('div').html(v * 120);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vWf2x/2/

Comment: Thanks for this but if i mistakenly type a letter, I can not type anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/pBeM8/

You bind the keydown event to the input box in order to prevent the undesired characters from being entered, and bind the keyup event in order check the value & modify the div's height.

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
   if(!(e.which >= 48 && e.which <=58) && e.which !== 8 && e.which !== 46 && e.which !== 37 && e.which !== 39){ //prevent anything other than numeric characters, backspace, delete, and left & right arrows
       return false;
   }
})
.keyup(function(){
   val = $(this).val();
   if(val > 10){
       val = 10;
       $(this).val(10);
   }
   $('div').height(val * 10);
});
```

Comment: I really like your example but wouldn't be simple if you just show the result ?

Comment: What do you mean? I provided a link that shows the solution live. What more are you looking for?